# Postgres, RDW, WHERE condition not pushed to remote (JSONB attribute, using postgres_rdw)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I have a remote postgres table using RDW. It contains a JSONB column and I use values in that JSONB for the `WHERE` condition.

The remote table has a GIN index on the JSONB column and an index on the `hostname`-attribute that I use for filtering.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT 
* 
FROM forein_table
WHERE details->>'hostname' = 'host-xyz'
```

shows that the "Remote SQL" **does not contain** the `WHERE`-clause and filtering is done local. 
On the other hand

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT 
* 
FROM forein_table
WHERE details@> '{"hostname": "host-xyz"}'
```

**sends down** the 'WHERE' clause which is obviously much faster.

The documentation says:

> WHERE clauses are not sent to the remote server unless they use only built-in data types, operators, and functions. Operators and functions in the clauses must be IMMUTABLE as well.

Is there a difference between `->>` and `@>`?

Is there a way to use `WHERE details->>'hostname' = 'host-xyz'` on a remote table and have it push down the `WHERE` clause?

(I found a way by creating a `VIEW` which extracts the `hostname` attribute as a column, and then creating the remote table on this view...but obviously this is not a very flexible/elegant approach)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that in `details->>'hostname'`, 'hostname' is of a text type, and PostgreSQL cannot prove to itself either that the same default collation is in use on both sides of the FDW, or that the ->> operator will always return the same answer regardless of collation of its right argument.  So it won't push it over.

There has been some talk of adding a way to mark functions and operators as not being sensitive to collation.  But that won't done until at v12 at the earliest.

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that. Not what I was hoping for...but at least makes some sense now. Thanks.